# Powers and roots of large numbers in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to port (for learning) my Python code below to Go -- the Python works fine.

```
for n in range (81522017,81522025):
     b = int(str(n) + str(n+1)+str(n+2))
     if b**(1/3) % 1 == 0:
         print(n,b)
         break

//solution 81522019   and  815220198152202081522021
```

So in Go, I end up with:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "math"
)

func main() {
  
    for n:=81522017; n<81522025;n++{
      b:=(strconv.Itoa(n)+strconv.Itoa(n+1)+strconv.Itoa(n+2))
      bFloat, _ := (strconv.ParseFloat(b,64))
    
      if math.Mod((math.Pow((bFloat),(1.0/3.0))),1.0)   == 0 {
          fmt.Println(n,bFloat)  
      }    
    }
}
```

The condition in the if statement is never met and therefore the solution is not displayed.  I think this has something to do with precision of handling floats.

Ultimately, I am looking at taking the cube root of a large integer (815220198152202081522021 in this case) and checking to see if it is a pure integer -- hence the %1 in the Python code.

What am I missing -- there must be an easier way to do this....

Any help / pointers greatly received.

Comment: float64 has only 16 significant digits. Even a long double reaches about 19 digits. We're trying to give it 24 digits. Try printing the string value with the converted float64 value. You'll have to use math/big to get your program working.  Also, even a calculator has fractional part for the cube root of your solution 815220198152202081522021. (cube it and subtract to see).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you use Float % integers, let's say 69.777 % 1.0, it has to be 0.777, not 0, so it doesn't in if condition. You try this solution.This is add `int()` haha.

```golang
if int(math.Mod((math.Pow((bFloat),(1.0/3.0))),1.0)) == 0 {
    fmt.Println(n,bFloat)  
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks -- that doesnt do it.   For my code using Int as per your suggestion gives:  0.23606088757514954
0.6180304884910583
1.043081283569336e-07  <<<< This one should be zero 
0.38196972012519836
0.7639393508434296
0.14590895175933838
0.5278782397508621
0.9098478704690933

The only answer that should evaluate to zero on %1 is the one that starts with n= 81522019  -- ie the third one in this list.

Comment: To be clear -- the values calculated seem incorrect. 1.043081283569336e-07  << should in reality be zero.  I know its really close, but it should be exactly zero.

Comment: Open a bug in golang